# SQL query counting based on successive condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+--------+-------+-------+
|TestName|TestRun|OutCome|
+--------+-------+-------+
| Test1  | 1     | Fail  |
+--------+-------+-------+
| Test1  | 2     | Fail  |
+--------+-------+-------+
| Test2  | 1     | Fail  |
+--------+-------+-------+
| Test2  | 2     | Pass  |
+--------+-------+-------+
| Test3  | 1     | Pass  |
+--------+-------+-------+
| Test3  | 2     | Fail  |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

The table is used for storing a brief summary of test results. I want to write a query (using T-SQL but any dialect is fine) that returns how many build each test has been failing. Use the example as input and it should return a result set like this:

```
+--------+----------+
|TestName|Regression|
+--------+----------+
| Test1  | 2        |
+--------+----------+
| Test2  | 0        |
+--------+----------+
| Test3  | 1        |
+--------+----------+
```

**Note that the query should ONLY count current 'fail streak'** instead of counting the total number of failures. Can assume MAX(TestRun) is the most recent run.

Any ideas?

Edit: grammar

Comment: You can put `WHERE` before `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What *version* of SQL Server please

Comment: the version I'm using is 2008-r2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit ugly but it works.

```
create table dbo.tests
(
    TestName nvarchar(10) not null
    , TestRun int not null
    , OutCome nvarchar(10) not null
)

insert into dbo.tests
select 'Test1', 1, 'Fail'
union all 
select 'Test1', 3, 'Fail'
union all 
select 'Test2', 1, 'Fail'
union all 
select 'Test2', 3, 'Pass'
union all 
select 'Test3', 1, 'Pass'
union all 
select 'Test3', 3, 'Fail'

; with c (TestName, TestRun, OutCome, TestId)
as
(
    select TestName, TestRun, OutCome
            , dense_rank() over (order by TestRun) as TestId
    from dbo.tests
) 

select t.TestName, max(t.TestId) - mt.MaxPassedTestRun as FailedRuns
from c t
        inner join
            (
                select TestName, sum(TestId) as MaxPassedTestRun
                from
                    (
                        select TestName, TestId 
                        from c
                        where OutCome = 'Pass'

                        union all 

                        select TestName, 0 as TestRun
                        from c
                        where OutCome = 'Fail'
                    ) mt
                group by mt.TestName
            ) mt on t.TestName = mt.TestName
group by t.TestName, MaxPassedTestRun, mt.MaxPassedTestRun
```

Comment: Here only one problem(same in my answer) if numbers of `TestRun` will not increment by one. For example `TestRun=1` and next `TestRun = 4`

Comment: Updated with that requirement. Still requires that the id is increasing but not necessarily contiguous.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.TestName,a.TestRun,a.Outcome From table1 a join 
Table1 b on a.TestName=b.testname          
and a.Outcome='Fail' 
and a.TestRun>b.TestRun
```

Comment: Hi Sonam: Thank you for the rapid reply. Your query seems to be counting all failures though. the query should only be counting current 'fail streak' as in the example (Test2)

Comment: I've edited my query, please let me know if this is something close to what you are looking for or please elaborate more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using CTE:

```
;WITH streaks AS (
    SELECT t.Name, t.Run, t.Outcome 
    FROM TestRuns t
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Name, MAX(Run) AS MaxRun FROM TestRuns GROUP BY Name) maxes
    ON maxes.Name = t.Name AND maxes.MaxRun = t.Run

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.Name, t.Run, t.Outcome
    FROM TestRuns t
    INNER JOIN streaks s ON s.Name = t.Name AND s.Outcome = 0
    WHERE t.Run = s.Run - 1 AND t.Outcome = 0
)

SELECT Name
, SUM(CASE WHEN Outcome = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Regression
FROM streaks
GROUP BY Name
```

Here a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb405/23) with sample of data

Comment: Interesting approach... though still can't wrap my head around it (streaks joins with itself within its definition) yet. my tests suggest that it's correct. Thanks. p.s. SQL Fiddle looks pretty useful too

Comment: This is using of recursive queries with CTE(Common Table Expression), check this [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)